# Summarise survey of proportions

Tags: confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics

I have asked N individuals for their estimate of the presence and quality of phone numbers in a database, i.e. missing, wrong, correct. I have received triples of percentages, e.g. (20, 30, 50)

How do best summarize the result and provide confidence intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 'hierarchically'. First, choose one type of number, say missing, and compute percentages of two other types provided that they're not missing.

So for 20% missing, 30% wrong and 50% correct, you'll have 20% missing and among non-missing ones 5/8= 62.5% are correct, rest is wrong.

Now these two numbers (percent of missing numbers, percent of correct numbers among non-missing) are independent, so you can compute two CI's in usual way. The third one (for wrong, non-missing) will immedietaly follow from second one (
for correct, non-missing).

But note: I don't say that this is the best option. It is the one I find usefull.